# Google Analytic is not working in Sencha application

Tags: php, extjs, google-analytics, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Hello I have Sencha touch application Developed.

I need to integrate Google analytic with application.

I have ready java script with me which is running fine in PHP code.

PHP Code is given below.

```
 <script>
   (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
   (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
   m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
   })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

   ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X', 'narolainfotech.com');
   ga('send', 'pageview');
 </script>
 <?php
     print('Running Well');
 ?>
```

But when I try to add it in Sencha application. It does not work.

Can any body please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use: https://github.com/ggendre/GALocalStorage

Just insclude the file in your app.json

```
'js': [
    ...
    {"path": "app/utils/GALocalStorage.js"}
```

Place these two lines with your values in a script tag in the head of index.html

```
ga_storage._setAccount('--GA-ACCOUNT-ID--');
ga_storage._setDomain('--YOUR-DOMAIN--');
```

then you can:

```
ga_storage._trackPageview('/index', 'optional title');
ga_storage._trackEvent('category', 'action', 'label', 'value');
```

Hope it helps-

Comment: Great it did work!!! Can you please tell me why my code was not working... And what is the reason why your GALocalStorage's code works.